# Reverse Iteration Over Sparse Array in Bash (macOS)

Tags: bash, macos

I iterate forward over a sparse array:

`for j in "${!logArray[@]}"; ...`

and that works fine, but how can I iterate over the array in reverse?

(For my use case the indices are large integers and are very unlikely to be consecutive.)

Comment: Possibly answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27382/how-do-i-reverse-a-for-loop

Comment: That would be fine if it was a regular array or a sparse array with consecutive indices, but that's not the case.

Comment: You mean this: declare -a logArray=() - or do you want to see the indices?

Comment: Yes, but my first response was for that array after it had just been declared and was empty - hence the result. What do you want to see? The fully populated array is rather large ;)

Comment: I used a small data set with these resulting indices: 357,1557,1602,1719,2218,2481,2860,2965,2968,3524,3539,5558,7248,7309,9245,12417,12488,14274,15087,27368,27530,27914,28067,28192,30037,30038,30039,33875,35453,35738,37890,38703,39773,42866,42939,55244,55323,55352,56249,57119,60186,62371,64273,64589,66554,69315,81640

Comment: Get the keys as a string, pass that string through `tac`, then `for .. in` over the reversal?

Comment: I guess that would work. I'll give it a try, but I am hoping for something more straightfwd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a second, dense and continuous, array of the indices of the first array, and iterate over *its* indices in reverse order.

```
indices=("${!logArray[@]}")
n="${#indices[@]}"
for ((i=n-1; i>=0; i--)); do
   echo "${logArray[${indices[$i]}]}"
done
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks! (With all due respect) pretty obvious really, but I tend not to see the obvious.

Comment: FWIW, the for loop could be `for i in "${!indices[@]}"; do echo "${logArray[indices[-i-1]]}"; done`

Comment: @rici Assuming you are using `bash` 4.2 or later, yes. (Although since I did define `n`, you could use `for i in "${!indices[@]}"; do echo "${logArray[${indices[n-1-i]}]}"; done`.)

Comment: I've only just got around to trying this.  I think the first line should be: `indices=($!logArray[@]}`

Comment: Indeed it should be (plus some not-strictly-necessary quotes to establish good habit). I thought I had copy-pasted the working example into the answer, but apparently I had not.